# why does my Xcode swift app now fail to open after adding swift framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My swift iOS app was working fine until I added framework...

1. Built swift framework.
2. dragged its .xcodeproj into my app's project pane
3. Added framework to target >> General tab >> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content
4. Mach-O Type set to Dynamic Lib

Now app displays for an instant on iOS device, then disappears and fails to run and Mac displays:
"Could not launch "

...and Xcode console shows:
error: failed to launch '/private/var/containers/

> Bundle/Application/B02F96F5-B4D7-4800-B133-2340AEDD4A41/KP_to_iOS_2.app'
> -- The operation couldn’t be completed. The process failed to launch.

Comment: You don't get anything in the xcode console when this happens?

Comment: Does it works In simulator ?

Comment: Max 6, I get this:  "error: failed to launch '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B02F96F5-B4D7-4800-B133-2340AEDD4A41/KP_to_iOS_2.app' -- The operation couldn’t be completed. The process failed to launch."